# What site can I use to generate a custom sources.list?

Tags: software-sources, official-repositories

I've just installed Ubuntu 11.04, after installing 10.10 I found a real useful official site which compiles a `/etc/apt/source.list` that can be copied and pasted, and a list of the key commands for terminal. I don't seem to be able to find it now and the only others I can find are generic lists that others have made.

Comment: Do you mean http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ ---I am not sure that you can trust it 100%

Comment: Yes I thats exactly what I wanted, you say not to trust it though, why not? What else would you suggest?

Comment: That link is fairly standard, I would use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site in question is [RepoGen](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/).